# Finding the position of occurrence of a word in a string

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a pipe delimited string "Y|Y|Y|N|N". How can I find the position of first occurrence of N using code after processing the string.

Comment: The comments to the answers suggest that you need to edit this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your question should read:

"I have a pipe delineated string. I want the index of something in the string once the pipes have been removed"

```
// first occurrence of string "N" if you simply remove the pipes first.
var str:String = "Y|Y|Y|N|N";
var index:int = str.replace("|","").indexOf("N");
```

Because removing the pipes can actually concatenate strings and lead to false positives, you may want to consider the following:

```
var str:String = "Y|Y|Y|N|N";
var pieces:Array = str.split("|");
for( var i:int = 0; i < pieces.length; i++ )
{
    if( pieces[ i ] == "N" ) break;
}
// i will now be the first index.
```

if you're just looking for removal of the pipe, str.replace works in AS3, in AS2 you need to use str.split("|").join("");

Answer (score 1):

AS3 supports a lot of such simple tasks,

For your problem simply use:

```
str.indexOf("N");
```

where str is your string.

Read more about string functions, [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html).

---

**EDIT:**

That's not a problem either, that's why I linked you to as3 docs.You will hardly need regular expressions.

```
str.replace("|","").indexOf("N");
```

Comment: Whoops! Sorry. I should have made myself more clear. The code should first remove the pipe strings. That should make it YYYNN. Then find the index. The pipe string should not be considered when finding the index.(I am not from an AS3 background)

Comment: Edited answer, as per your comments.

Answer (score 0):

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=12_Using_Regular_Expressions_01.html

Your expression will be something like "/Y\|Y\|Y\|(.)\|.\|/" (I haven't tested this...)

A good place to test it: http://ryanswanson.com/regexp/#start

Comment: Whoops! Sorry. I should have made myself more clear. The code should first remove the pipe strings. My actual doubt how can I remove the pipe strings and make it into a single string

Comment: I would go with @cwallenpoole then.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you correctly... Have you read http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary692.html?

*indexOf* returns the position of the substring you search for in the string.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry. I should have made myself more clear. The code should first remove the pipe strings. My actual doubt how can I remove the pipe strings and make it into a single string.